# API gateway SQS response ends with UnknownOperationException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs

I have an API Gateway which routes requests to SQS, API Gateway has a the needed permission to send messages to SQS (Created IAM role), when I send test data, I'll get the response below with UnknownOperationException.

SQS is also empty with no messages available.

```
Tue Nov 09 13:46:11 UTC 2021 : Sending request to https://sqs.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXX/XXXX
Tue Nov 09 13:46:11 UTC 2021 : Received response. Status: 404, Integration latency: 2 ms
Tue Nov 09 13:46:11 UTC 2021 : Endpoint response headers: {x-amzn-RequestId=e63b5577-9866-569d-85d8-0f73e5851cf0, Date=Tue, 09 Nov 2021 13:46:11 GMT, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-618a7ba3-dd93ee11df45d437f9c98705, Content-Type=null, Content-Length=29}
Tue Nov 09 13:46:11 UTC 2021 : Endpoint response body before transformations: <UnknownOperationException/>

Tue Nov 09 13:46:11 UTC 2021 : Method response body after transformations: <UnknownOperationException/>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

To fix that issue you have to add the Content-Type:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' header to the integration request:
[integration request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VyPA.png)